# Can bcache have non-zero dirty cache forever?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raid, bcache

I created a Raspberry Pi based bcache on SSD with a HDD based RAID 1 array. After populating the RAID with few TB of content, bcache showed 10% dirty cache. That would be expected, since I have `/sys/block/bcache0/bcache/cache_mode` set to `writeback`. However, it stays at 10% indefinitely. The device is running for days without any activity. I even tried to force the cache flush by

```
echo 0 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/writeback_percent
```

Which was properly set, but no disk activity started, as evidenced by `iostat`, the dirty cache still remains at 10%.

Does this mean there's something wrong with bcache? Should I worry, or is there any explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be expected behaviour.

> Write-back mode is usually safe because the caching device is journalled. Bcache will rewrite all dirty data after (unexpected) reboots to the persistent backing device, in fact bcache doesn't even finish writing dirty data at shutdown as part of its design, it will always boot dirty and continue writing back dirty data and reliably finish filesystem transactions. Only when the backing device has ack'ed all data written, the caching data is marked clean.

From: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:Bcache#Whole_article_revamp

Comment: You are probably right, seems to be by design. That said, at least in my case, I'd consider it to be dangerous, as my SSD can fail and the data would never make it safely to the backing (RAID 1) device. For the reference, I moved to ZFS on my Raspberry, at least I don't have to rebuild kernel for each upgrade.